# How are second-countability and Hausdorff property preserved under isomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

I really have a main and a side question.

(**Main question**):

(**Preamble**) We know that the set of all $n\times m$ complex matrices $M_{n, m}(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{R}^{2(n\times m)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2nm}$. We also know that under the standard topology of Euclidean spaces, $\mathbb{R}^k$ is Hausdorff and second-countable for any $k\geq 1$. Since isomorphism between two spaces is a way of saying that a space $A$ is mapped to space $B$ (and vice-versa) such that the structures of $A$ and $B$ are preserved, it would make sense to me that $M_{n, m}(\mathbb{C})$ is also Hausdorff and second-countable under the isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^{2nm}$.

(**Question itself**) Therefore isn't it true that if $(S_1, \tau_1)$, $(S_2, \tau_2)$ are two topological spaces such that $(S_2, \tau_2)$ is second-countable and Hausdorff and there exists an isomorphism $f:S_1 \to S_2$, then $(S_1, \tau_1)$ is second-countable and Hausdorff as well. Moreover, isn't the only important property the bijectivity of the mapping?

(**Side question**): While we can quite easily equip a topology for  $M_{n, m}(\mathbb{C})$ when $n = m$ by only considering invertible matrices, what is a sensible to way to create a topology when $n \neq m$? Should one consider matrix norms or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by equipping a topology for $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$ when $n = m$ by considering invertible matrices?

Comment: Your question is correct, and it's, one could say, trivial to verify. Homeomorphisms (that's how "isomorphisms" of topological spaces are called) are maps which are bijective both on the set itself and on the topologies, but no, bijectiveness of the map alone doesn't suffice.

Comment: @Jakobian For your first answer: By "equipping a topology" I mean that I'd form a collection of complex valued matrices which are invertible. For your second answer: So then it would be valid to say that: As $\mathbb{R}^{2nm}$ is Hausdorff and second-countable, so is $M_{m, n}(\mathbb{C})$ by an existing homeomorphism?